# How to remove intermediate images from a build after the build?

Tags: docker, docker-build

When you build your multi-stage Dockerfile with

```
docker build -t myimage .
```

it produces the final image tagged `myimage`, and also intermediate images. To be completely clear we are talking here not about containers, but about images. It looks like this:

[image]

See these `<none>` images? These are what I'm talking about.

Now this "issue" has been discussed to some extent [here](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/34151) and [here](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/34513).

Here are some relevant parts:

> If these intermediate images would be purged/pruned automatically, the build cache would be gone with each build, therefore forcing you to rebuild the entire image each time.

So okay, it does not make sense to prune then *automatically*.

Some people do this:

> For now, I'm using `docker image prune -f` after my `docker build -t app .` command to cleanup those intermediate images.

But unfortunately this is not something I can do. As one discussion participant commented:

> It removes "all dangling images", so in shared environments (like Jenkins slave) it's more akin to shooting oneself in the foot. :)

And this is a scenario I found myself in.

So nothing to be "fixed" on Docker side. But how can I remove those extra images, **from a single particular build only**?

**Update**

After reading very nice answer from d4nyll below, which is a big step forward, I'd like to add some more constraints to the question ;) First, let me sum up the answer:

- One can use [ARG](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg) to pass a build id from CI/CD to `Dockerfile` builder
- Then one can use [LABEL](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#label) syntax to add build id metadata to the stage images being built
- Then one can use the `--filter` option of [docker image prune](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_prune/#options) command to remove only the images with the current build id

This *is* a big step forward, but I'm still struggling into how to fit it into my usage scenario without adding unnecessary complexity.

In my case a requirement is that application developers who author the Dockerfiles and check them into the source control system are responsible for making sure that their Dockerfiles build the image to their satisfaction. They are not required to craft all their Dockerfiles in a specific way, "so our CI/CD process does not break". They simply have to provide a `Dockerfile` that produce correct docker image.

Thus, I'm not really in a position to request them to add stuff in the `Dockerfile` for every single application, just for the sake of CI/CD pipeline. This is something that CI/CD pipeline is expected to handle all by itself.

The only way I can see making this work is to write a `Dockerfile` parser, that will detect multi-staged build and inject a label per stage and then build that modified `Dockerfile`. This is a complexity that I'm very hesitant to add to the CI/CD pipeline.

Do I have a better (read simpler) options?

Comment: have you ever tried this for cleaning the dangled images:-

`docker rmi $(docker images -f "dangling=true" -q)`

Comment: @kakabali yes and it worked. Not helping with the problem at hand though.

Comment: oops sorry for that :-( . may be having a separate area(another docker image having docker installed inside itself) where you can push and image to the registry and then remove this container/ image after things have finished

Comment: @kakabali docker in docker does not work well, this is a know fact many discovered from experience and docker developers do not recommend using it explicitly. There are many subtle issues. Google about it if you are interested.

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh what is interesting and no one mentions, after restarting the system these "dangling" images disappear from 'docker images'

Answer (score 73, accepted):

As [`ZachEddy`](https://github.com/ZachEddy) and [`thaJeztah`](https://github.com/thaJeztah) [mentioned](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/34513#issuecomment-389250632) in one of the issues you linked to, you can label the intermediate images and `docker image prune` those images based on this label.

**Dockerfile** (using multi-stage builds)

```
FROM node as builder
LABEL stage=builder
...

FROM node:dubnium-alpine
...
```

After you've built you image, run:

```
$ docker image prune --filter label=stage=builder
```

---

### For Automation Servers (e.g. Jenkins)

If you are running the builds in an automation server (e.g. Jenkins), and want to remove only the intermediate images from that build, you can

1. Set a unique build ID as an environment variable inside your Jenkins build
2. Add an [`ARG`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg) instruction for this build ID inside your `Dockerfile`
3. Pass the build ID to [`docker build`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/) through the [`--build-arg`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#set-build-time-variables---build-arg) flag

```
FROM node as builder
ARG BUILD_ID
LABEL stage=builder
LABEL build=$BUILD_ID
...

FROM node:dubnium-alpine
...
```

```
$ docker build --build-arg BUILD_ID .
$ docker image prune --filter label=stage=builder --filter label=build=$BUILD_ID
```

If you want to persists the build ID in the image (perhaps as a form of documentation accessible within the container), you can add another `ENV` instruction that takes the value of the `ARG` build argument. This also allows you to use the similar [environment replacement](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#environment-replacement) to set the label value to the build ID.

```
FROM node as builder
ARG BUILD_ID
ENV BUILD_ID=$BUILD_ID
LABEL stage=builder
LABEL build=$BUILD_ID
...

FROM node:dubnium-alpine
...
```

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh Perhaps you can set a unique build ID as an environment variable inside your Jenkins build, add it to the image using `ENV`, and use [environment replacement](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#environment-replacement) to use that build ID as the label value

Comment: Yes you'd need to modify the `Dockerfile` to include the `ENV` and `LABEL` instructions. I am not sure why this is a complex procedure, would you mind clarifying?

Comment: A `LABEL` instruction is not going to interfere with your build process. The label is purely metadata that the `docker` daemon uses. Nothing 'inside' the image itself gets changed. I'd advise you to read the documentation more closely, as this is precisely what the `LABEL` instructure is made for. If you find yourself implement your own `Dockerfile` parser, you are over-complicating things.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189780/discussion-between-andrew-savinykh-and-d4nyll).

Answer (score 5):

We're doing exactly this, applying labels to the Dockerfile at build-time like this:

```
sed -i '/^FROM/a\
LABEL build_id=${env.BUILD_TAG}\
' Dockerfile
```

Probably too late to help the OP, but hopefully this will be useful to someone facing the same problem.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you for sharing this.

Answer (score 4):

A little late, but the best option is

`docker builder prune -a`

[image]

Comment: That does not remove images **from a single particular build only** as bolded in the question.

Comment: After upgrading to the latest docker version, builder cache no longer appears as images. I found this to be the only way to remove intermediate "images" and free up disk space. (docker image ls only shows about 5GB total usage, and docker builder prune cleaned up 17GB intermediate builder cache for me, which previously can be cleaned by docker image rm.)

Answer (score 3):

You can run docker build inserting another param wich will remove automatically the intermediate images:

```
docker build --force-rm -t myimage .
```

Comment: This question is about [multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) and removing images from this particular type of build. Your suggestion does not solve it. Did you try it yourself before proposing?

Answer (score 2):

The easy way is to run the cmd  `docker rmi -f $(docker images -f "dangling=true" -q)`

Comment: An even easier way is to run `docker image prune` since it cleans up only dangling images by default. https://docs.docker.com/config/pruning/

Comment: The question explains in great details, why this is not an answer we are looking for. Have you read the entire question?

Answer (score -3):

If you do not want to use the cache at all, you can use the --no-cache=true option on the docker build command

[Leverage build cache](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#leverage-build-cache)

Comment: This question is about [multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) and removing images from this particular type of build. Your suggestion does not solve it. Did you try it yourself before proposing?

Comment: You are right, but then subject is wrong and google leads to this answer in stackoverflow. So not useful

Answer (score -5):

Please use the below command for deleting all intermediate images:

```
docker rmi $(docker images -a|grep "<none>"|awk '$1=="<none>" {print $3}')
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Briefly describe what your command does and if there may be any side effects.